# ibeacon - Inconsistent detection of beacons by raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, ibeacon

I am using raspberry pi for detecting beacons but many times I have observed that there is inconsistent detection of beacons by raspberry pi. Some of beacons are not getting detect by raspberry pi and some of getting detected once but after some time it not at all getting detecting.

I am using node noble (1.8.1) module for detecting beacons.

RaspberryPi - Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with inbuilt bluetooth.

```
noble.on('discover', function(peripheral) {

  var id = peripheral.id;
  var entered = !inRange[id];

  if (entered) {
    inRange[id] = {
      peripheral: peripheral
    };
    var time = Date.now()-inRange[id].lastSeen;
    console.log(peripheral.id);

  inRange[id].lastSeen = Date.now();
});
```

I have searched regarding this but did't get any solution or resolution on it.

Comment: I'd start by troubleshooting the beacons you never see get detected by your Pi. Can you see these beacons with another scanner like and Android or iOS device?

Comment: Yes.Each and every time same beacons get detected by Android App but not on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What is different about them vs the ones you do see on the Pi?

Comment: Hi David , each and every time beacons get detected by android app but in case of 
 Pi there is no surety of detection for all beacons.I observed that in case of Pi some of the beacons ware not getting detected while some of them were detecting as per expatiation but at a time all the beacons were detected by android app. I am not able to figure it out where is the problem , is it from software side(node module - noble that I am using ) or on hardware side(PI inbuilt bluetooth).